# Unable to resolve identifier: 'COL"

Tags: c++, identifier

I have this identifier

```
#define COL 32
```

I use it to create a number of arrays, which all work fine. However, to debug the part of code I'm at, I added COL to watch (Visual Studio) and got an "Unable to resolve identifier" message instead of a value. The code compiles and runs fine, but I can not check certain stuff. I have tried to comment out the function I'm workong on, in case I did something there, but that didn't help. I have been working on the code for weeks, it always worked fine, I have not updated anything, I'm totally at a loss...

Comment: `COL` is not a variable, in all the places `COL` is used in code it will be "replaced" with it's value: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor

Comment: I think you shouldn't have been able to watch this in the first place, as it's not an identifier, or, if you _can_ do this, but get complaints from VS, it's either a bug or a misconfiguration. To my mind, VS is absolute BS, so switch to Linux and use mere GCC or clang.

Comment: I can print the value with cout << "COL " << COL<< "\n";

Comment: Does that mean, that I never could "watch" this value, but simply didn't stumble upon it? I can not recall.

Comment: @Flisp - Of course you do, the code is in fact `cout << "COL" << 32 << "\n";`

Comment: What is there to "watch"? It cannot change.

Comment: I know I've seen some debugger which was somehow aware of preprocessor macros via debug info, but can't remember which one. But yes, this would take extra effort, since they're eliminated so early in the translation process.

Comment: I simplified - or misunderstood - the problem. The value I wanted to watch was Wap2iW3[i * COL / MMsize + x], and got the error. So I reduced it.

Answer (score 0):

Macros are **replaced** by the preprocessor at the earliest stage of compilation. There is no `COL` symbol in your code after that.

If you use C++, do it the C++ way:

```
namespace constants {
    constexpr int coloums = 32;
}
```

The preprocessors uses are becoming fewer and far between every time the C++ standard is revised. We don't need it to define integral constants, never did in fact.

Comment: Thank you! I replaced all my #define and now I can follow all values.

Comment: @Flisp - Glad it was sorted out for you :)